# Laravel 5.2 - remove duplicate records based on values

Tags: laravel-5

I have a few hundred duplicate records just like the one shown in the image below. With laravel I wan't to remove the duplicates based on `groupid` and `studentid`  where `groupid = NULL`. I achieved this using iterations on records keeping flags and all.. I wan't to do it in a cleaner way with Laravel. Help!

[image]

Comment: Just get the corresponding Entities with `YourModelName::whereGroupId(null)` and delete them

Comment: your query will remove all entries I only want the duplicates to be removed